# Как прочитать последнюю запись из таблицы, приравнять к переменной?

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток. Есть запрос:

```sql
SELECT id_b FROM flop WHERE id_a='$id' ORDER BY flop.id_b DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Короче говоря, вытаскиваю последнюю запись из таблицы (но не из всей, а по условию `id_a='$id'`).

Как определить, чему равно `id_b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT `id_b` FROM `flop` WHERE `id_a`='.$id.' ORDER BY `flop`.`id_b` DESC LIMIT 0, 1');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['id_b'];
```

Читайте [документацию](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) по mysql-функциям.

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало. Но сработало 1 раз, где при WHERE `id_a`='.$id.' записей нет. Когда записи есть, то значение 'id_b' =  последнему в таблице.

Comment: могу быть не прав, но вроде с "LIMIT 0, 1" работать не должно. вот если эту хрень стерерь, то все сработает. а в обще, ответ выше правильный

Comment: Ну да, сработало правильно. А вам как надо?

Comment: Пишите, пожалуйста, предложения полностью - понять вас очень трудно.
`if(mysql_num_rows($res)){/*действия, если найдено что-то*/}` - вы это имели в виду?
Подсчитать кол-во записей - `$total = mysql_num_rows($res);`. При `limit 0,1` $total всегда будет от 0 до 1.

Comment: Код:

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flop WHERE id_a=$id"); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res); $total = $row[0]; // сколько записей
    if ($total == 0) {$ent = 0;} // если записей 0, то  $ent = 0
    else {
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT `id_b` FROM `flop` WHERE `id_a`='.$id.' ORDER BY `flop`.`id_b` DESC LIMIT 0, 1');
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    echo $row['id_b'];
    }

Comment: Диагноз таков: первый раз, все работает нормально, $row['id_b'] равен тому, что мне нужно. Потом я прибавляю к нему 1 и в месте с другими данными, все попадает в таблицу. Потом при этом же или другом id_b, значение id_b равняется последнему значению в таблице уже без d_a='.$id.'. Как будто в запросе этой фразы и нету.

Comment: Значит, либо неправильно пишете в БД, либо у вас такая логика, что id_b равняется последнему значению в таблице уже без d_a=$id.

Comment: ок. пойду разбираться